# Git merge: Already up to date

Tags: git, git-merge

Я сделал checkout удаленной ветки, все прошло нормально.
Далее делаю обновление **git pull**, провожу изменения с локальной веткой и делаю **commit**. Изменения мне не понравились, и я решил сделать некий реверт: **git fetch; git merge**. Но получил: *up-to-date*.

Получается, что локальный бранч старше удаленного, и поэтому он не ревертит меня.
Подскажите, почему это происходит и какие критерии успешного **git merge**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разумеется, локальный старше, но это тут ни при чём, даже если удалённый старше, **git pull** делает `merge` между вашими и удалёнными изменениями. Причём он сначала как раз и делает `fetch` (только добавляет изменения в ваше хранилище с удалённого в отдельную ветку, ваши коммиты сохраняются), а потом merge вашей и удалённой ветки.

Пока вы не сделали **`git push`**, можно откатить локальные изменения — **`git reset`** с разными ключами в зависимости от того, хотите вы сохранить изменения в файлах или откатить вместе с хранилищем.
А если сделали push, то **`git revert`** создаст отменяющий коммит, и в удалённом репозитории оба коммита останутся на память.

Критерий хорошего merge - мало конфликтов. Конфликты устраняете в редакторе ища символы `<<<<`, потом делаете `add` и `commit`.

Ещё перед `git pull` и разными объединениями, перестановками коммитов желательно отложить текущие незакоммиченные изменения в специально предназначенную для этого временную ветку **`git stash`**, а потом восстановить **`git stash pop`**.

Comment: К вышесказанному добавлю приятную команду гита `git log --color --graph`

Comment: "но это тут ни при чём", а почему тогда он не перетер мои измененный закомиченные данные после pull? Они же отличаются!

Comment: если так хочется перетереть, 
git fetch
git reset --hard origin/master  
если что я не виноват

Comment: @gcoder ахах хорошая попытка

Comment: если совсем по хорошему, то нужно сделать вначале `git reflog` - это покажет локальную пользовательскую историю (это именно локальная!!!). Там по истории найти sha hash нужного состояния. Потом выполнить команду вида `git reset --hard <sha>` и проверить состояние кода. Если оно не удоволетворительное, повторить вышеуказанную процедуру до получения желаемого результата.

Comment: @KoVadim а подскажите, какое условие на то что *merge* выполним? Как git это определяет? Это касается моего кейса

Comment: merge выполним, если нет конфликтов. Есть несколько видов (стратегий) merge. Например, fast-forward. Это случается, если есть две ветки, у которых все коммиты общие плюс одна ветка имеет несколько дополнительных коммитов. В этом случае можно просто передвинуть указатель ветки.

Есть merge рекурсивный. Это когда у двух веток есть общий предок (а он всегда есть). В этом случае просматриваются все коммиты до общего и для каждого файла находиться оптимальное слияние.

git не может сделать merge, если поменялся один и тот же кусок кода.

`git fetch; git merge` - это не revert. Это просто `git push

Comment: @KoVadim git pull вы хотели сказать?

Comment: Да, просто опечатался. Но когда увидел, уже подкоректировать нельзя было. А @Виталина подобное не исправит.